# Starter love2d physics program not working

Tags: box2d, lua, love2d

I am starting out with my first love2d (using LöVE 0.8) physics program. I am just creating some ground/floor, a car body and attaching two wheels with revolute joints and setting the motors a-go.

However, the car stands still, whereas I expect it to move. Can someone glance over the code below and see what I am doing wrong?

***UPDATE*** See below!

```
function love.load()

  -- Set up world
  love.physics.setMeter(50)
  world = love.physics.newWorld(0, 9.81*50, true)

  -- Window dimensions
  windim = {height = love.graphics.getHeight(), width = love.graphics.getWidth()}

  objects = {}

  -- Ground/Floor
  objects.ground = {}
  objects.ground.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 300, windim.height)
  objects.ground.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(2000,20)
  objects.ground.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.ground.body, objects.ground.shape)
  objects.ground.fixture:setFriction(3)

  -- Body of the car; a rectangle
  objects.carbody = {}
  objects.carbody.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 300, 500, "dynamic")
  objects.carbody.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(100,40)
  objects.carbody.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.carbody.body, objects.carbody.shape)  
  objects.carbody.fixture:setFriction(3)
  objects.carbody.fixture:setDensity(3)
  objects.carbody.fixture:setRestitution(0)  

  -- First wheel
  objects.wheel = {}
  objects.wheel.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 330, 520, "dynamic")
  objects.wheel.shape = love.physics.newCircleShape(20)
  objects.wheel.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.wheel.body, objects.wheel.shape)
  objects.wheel.fixture:setFriction(3)
  objects.wheel.fixture:setDensity(3)
  objects.wheel.fixture:setRestitution(0.6)

  -- Second wheel
  objects.wheel2 = {}
  objects.wheel2.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 270, 520, "dynamic")
  objects.wheel2.shape = love.physics.newCircleShape(20)
  objects.wheel2.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.wheel2.body, objects.wheel2.shape)
  objects.wheel2.fixture:setFriction(3)
  objects.wheel2.fixture:setDensity(3)
  objects.wheel2.fixture:setRestitution(0.6)

  -- Create joint between car body and first wheel
  objects.carbody.wheeljoint1 = love.physics.newRevoluteJoint(objects.carbody.body, objects.wheel.body, 330, 520)
  objects.carbody.wheeljoint1:enableMotor() 
  objects.carbody.wheeljoint1:setMaxMotorTorque(10000) -- Following example from http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/08/22/step-by-step-creation-of-a-box2d-cartruck-with-motors-and-shocks/

  -- Create joint between car body and second wheel
  objects.carbody.wheeljoint2 = love.physics.newRevoluteJoint(objects.carbody.body, objects.wheel2.body, 270, 520)
  objects.carbody.wheeljoint2:enableMotor() 
  objects.carbody.wheeljoint2:setMaxMotorTorque(10000)

end

function love.update(dt)
  -- Set contstant speed for the wheels
  objects.carbody.wheeljoint1:setMotorSpeed(20)
  objects.carbody.wheeljoint2:setMotorSpeed(20)

  world:update(dt)

end

function love.draw()
  love.graphics.print(objects.carbody.wheeljoint1:getMotorSpeed(), 10, 10)

  -- Render ground
  love.graphics.setColor(72, 160, 14)
  love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.ground.body:getWorldPoints(objects.ground.shape:getPoints()))

  -- Render car body
  love.graphics.setColor(72, 160, 200)
  love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.carbody.body:getWorldPoints(objects.carbody.shape:getPoints()))  

  -- Render wheels
  love.graphics.setColor(193, 47, 14)
  love.graphics.circle("line", objects.wheel.body:getX(), objects.wheel.body:getY(), objects.wheel.shape:getRadius())   
  love.graphics.circle("line", objects.wheel2.body:getX(), objects.wheel2.body:getY(), objects.wheel2.shape:getRadius())  
end
```

***UPDATE***
I added a line to print the angle of one of the wheels (see below). When this line is present, suddenly the car flips over from the wheels spinning when it hits the ground. This leads me to believe that something did not get initialized properly first time around.

This is the line added:

```
function love.draw()
  love.graphics.print(objects.wheel.body:getAngle(), 10, 10) -- Line added
```

Comment: I usually recommend new LOVErs to avoid `love.physics` until they're comfortable with the rest of love2d, but you clearly know what you're doing. :D

Comment: Not really. Lots of trial and error and fishing for examples on the web :-/

Comment: @m The definition of programming, basically! :p The web wisens as you ask.

Answer (score 2):

After playing around with this for a while, I finally discovered that my calls to `enableMotor` were wrong.

I was just saying

```
enableMotor()
```

when what it actually needed is

```
enableMotor(true)
```